# Camera2 Effects is not applied to neither the preview nor the photo

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, effect

When I try to apply the camera effect in my camera application that uses the camera2 api, where I can adjust the camera settings such as awb, brightness in runtime successfully, there is no change in the neither preview nor captured picture. However when I look to see if the effect has been applied to the camera by checking `characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AVAILABLE_EFFECTS)` I see it applied. I am using a device with Android 10 operating system.

The setEffect function:

```
public void setCameraEffect(int cameraEffect){
        try{
            mCameraCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
            previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE, cameraEffect);
            CaptureRequest previewRequest = previewRequestBuilder.build();
            mCameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequest, mCaptureCallback, mHandler);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AVAILABLE_EFFECTS)` tells you which effects are supported by that camera, not which effect is currently applied.

You'll need to look if the effect you want to apply is actually listed in `CONTROL_AVAILABLE_EFFECTS`.  If it's not, then it's not supported by the device.